# slide toggle on ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problem controlling my slidetoggle I want to show the months of the year i hovered but when i hover on 2015 the month for 2014 also slidetoggle how do I do that.

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy15gqxe/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="year">
    <li>2015
        <ul class="months">
            <li>Jan</li>
            <li>feb</li>
        </ul>
</li>
    <li>2014
        <ul class="months">
            <li>march</li>
            <li>april</li>
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.months { display: none; }
```

SCRIPT:

```
   $(".year").hover(function () {
    $(".months").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: You are selecting any elements with the month class (meaning all will slide) try to use a [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) instead so only the child `.month` of the hovered year gets toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your selector bit more specific (find the children `months` that is direct descendant of hovered `li`). Also you have invalid html (`ul` cannot be directly nested inside another `ul`).

Try:

```
//Bind event on the `li` that is direct descendant of .year
$(".year > li").hover(function () {
    //Get its direct descendant `.months` and toggle
    $(this).children(".months").stop(true).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

and

```
<ul class="year">
    <li>2015
        <ul class="months">
            <li>Jan</li>
            <li>feb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2014
        <ul class="months">
            <li>march</li>
            <li>april</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3mt2roo/)**

Another example wrapping the label and using sibling selector:

```
$(".year > li > span").hover(function (e) {
    $(this).next().stop(true).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

and

```
<ul class="year">
    <li><span>2015</span>
        <ul class="months">
            <li>Jan</li>
            <li>feb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>2014</span>
        <ul class="months">
            <li>march</li>
            <li>april</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q04byqse/)**